# is it idiomatic to say "the plastic tube is broken"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> [broken](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/broken_1?q=broken) (adj) that has been damaged or injured; no longer whole or working correctly
>
> a broken window/plate
>
> a broken leg/arm/bone
>
> pieces of broken glass
>
> How did this dish get broken?
>
> The TV's broken.
>
> They opened the bag and found a broken bottle.

Look at the picture

[image]

This is a plastic tube that is cut in half with scissors.

Normally, we say "**broken plate / bowl / cup**" for non-plastic things that drop.

A plastic tube can never split apart if you drop it. You can only damage it by cutting it apart with scissors, for example.

is it idiomatic to say "**the plastic tube is broken**"?

or do we say "**it is split apart**"?

Comment: It appears to be _cut in half_ or _cut in two_.

Comment: _Broken_ suggests accidental damage, and is usually used of a hard substance like crockery or bone. I would say the tube had been cut open. If the damage had happened accidentally because the plastic had become brittle with age, I would say it had split open.